# Why isn't my GPU rendering anything in blender (cycles)?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, command-line

I have a non-compatible GPU that I want to use in blender. I realize that you can't use non-compatible GPUs, but I saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=91AHD8YYAPc) where someone uses the windows command prompt to enable it. To my surprise, the video worked, and I saw my Radeon R9 200 series under OpenCL, enabled. However, when I tried to use it, blender would not show anything in cycles. It was all grey aside from the UI elements. I assumed blender wasn't doing anything, so I tried again, and again, until I realized it was writing things in the command prompt. The first time, it wrote the same 40 or so lines repeatedly for about about 15 times. [image]It then wrote this [image] and the final time I ran it it wrote this [image] The final line in the last screenshot is the last thing it wrote. After that, it did not write anything for 15 minutes, and then crashed. It would not display anything on the screen nor viewport render anything either of the 3 times. Is there any way to fix this, or is it just because I am using an incompatible GPU?

Comment: I have also a R9 200 GPU and it seems there is no official support of openCL above Version 1.2 (according to various websites). Beside of that, my amd software dont show any kind of openCL support (under Hardware-Details it says 'not available'). However, Blender needs Version 2 and above. I didnt try your workaround but if i get it right, you only set CYCLES_OPENCL_TEST to ALL which only tell Blender to ignore the requirements and give it a try anyway. This will work sometimes but apparently not for R9 200 series. I dont think there is an easy solution.

Comment: Should I just get another GPU, or is there another workaround that is possible?

Comment: Get another GPU. But unfortunately at the moment the market is empty. You will have to pay high prices. Maybe the best advise is to wait for better times if you can.